# Set a variable to be the result of a function only executes one time in a loop. Why?

Tags: javascript

Alright, so I have this code, where a `function` returns a `boolean`

This code should be executed in a `for` loop. But it only gets executed one time. Why is this so?

```js
function a(){
    alert("in a execution");
    var ret = true;
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        
    
        ret = ret && b();
    }
};

function b(){
    alert("in b execution");
    return false;
};

a();
```

If i would change my code to the following, it works. But why do I have to store the result of my function in an extra variable?

```js
function a(){
    alert("in a execution");
    var ret = true;
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        
        var bret = b();
        ret = ret && bret;
    }
};

function b(){
    alert("in b execution");
    return false;
};

a();
```

Comment: Just two words: short circuit.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari Someone should answer... Can you do it ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boolean function && works like this:
if you have

```
 a = false && b()
```

your function b() will never be executed, cause false && ANYTHING = false
You will have the same in such case:

```
 a = true || b()
```

true || ANYTHING = true always, so interpreter have not to know what is ANYTHING - true or false

Comment: VB.NET is an example of a language where this is not the case. MS didn't want to break code ported from VB6 (where And and Or are not short-circuited) so they introduced the shortcircuiting AndAlso and OrElse operators. Just when you thought VB couldn't get more unreadable...

Comment: I answered in JS context. You also could write 
    a = false & b() 
in javascript and your function b() would be executed.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation

> As logical expressions are evaluated left to right, they are tested
>   for possible "short-circuit" evaluation using the following rules:
>
> - `false && (anything)` is short-circuit evaluated to false.
> - `true || (anything)` is short-circuit evaluated to true.
>
> The rules of logic guarantee that these evaluations are always
>   correct. Note that the anything part of the above expressions is not
>   evaluated, so any side effects of doing so do not take effect. Also
>   note that the anything part of the above expression is any single
>   logical expression (as indicated by the parentheses).